# Coffeescript jQuery set data()

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

What am I doing wrong? I am trying to assign [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to each anchor. Now, the script only removes the title, but doesn't store anything in data(). When I tried `console.log(title)` it wrote the title fine, but still didn't store it. I'm using jQuery 1.7.1

I have the following lines in coffee

```
$(document).ready ->
    initBubble();

initBubble = ->
    $('a[title]').each (index, element) => 
        setInfoAttr($(element))

setInfoAttr = (element) ->
    title = element.attr('title')
    element.data('info', title).removeAttr('title')
```

The compiled output is as follows

```
(function() {
  var initBubble, setInfoAttr;

  $(document).ready(function() {
    return initBubble();
  });

  initBubble = function() {
    var _this = this;
    return $('a[title]').each(function(index, element) {
      return setInfoAttr($(element));
    });
  };

  setInfoAttr = function(element) {
    var title;
    title = element.attr('title');
    return element.data('info', title).removeAttr('title');
  };

}).call(this);
```

Comment: Looks like it should work fine... How are you testing to make sure the data is set?

Comment: I tried `console.log`. Apparently, it didn't work because of the order of functions (which is weird). Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe shuffle things around a little bit. Only thing I can see is that the initBubble function may be undefined when it is called.

```
initBubble = ->
    $('a[title]').each (index, element) => 
        setInfoAttr $(element)

setInfoAttr = (element) ->
    title = element.attr('title')
    element.data('info', title).removeAttr('title')

// A little shorcut for $(document).ready
$ ->
    initBubble()
```

Comment: yes that works, thank you! the function was defined fine, but the data attributes were in some kind of mess `$ ->` produces `$(function() {`, is that the same as `$(document).ready(function() {`?